# Array out of bounds exception, can't find the issue

Tags: java, arrays

Basicly, I am getting an ArrayOutOfBounds exception on line 19. I tried just pritning the array's contents without assigning any values(commented out the wile loop) but still the same error, anyone have a fix?

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    static int[][] Placer = new int[2][2]; //create multi-dimenstional array to hold the numbers

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random(); //intiallise new Random object
        int intsAssigned = 0; //will keep track of the ammount of ints assigned.



        //Assign all of the index's a random int, not the most practical way.
        while(intsAssigned != 9){
            int currentColumn = 0;
            Placer[currentColumn][0] = random.nextInt(20);
            Placer[currentColumn][1] = random.nextInt(20);
            Placer[currentColumn][2] = random.nextInt(20);
            currentColumn++;
            intsAssigned + 3;

        }
        printNumbers();

    }

    //Print all of the index's
    public static void printNumbers(){
        int numbersPrinted = 0;
        int currentColumn = 0;
        int currentRow = 0;
        while(numbersPrinted != 9){
            System.out.println(Placer[currentColumn][currentRow]);
            System.out.println(Placer[currentColumn][++currentRow]);
            System.out.println(Placer[currentColumn][currentRow + 2]);
            currentColumn++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah just saw that. Thanks, editting that now. Also what's the difference?

Comment: You also never seem to increment numbersPrinted, so that while won't exit. Instead, currentColumn will keep going up until it's out of bounds

Comment: Also, currentColumn is being initialized to 0 within the loop, so it won't ever be anything but 0 whenever it's used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placer is a `int[2][2]`... but you are trying to access `Placer[currentColumn][2]`. For an array of size 2, there are only two indices you can access: 0 and 1.

Perhaps you want `Placer` to be an `int[3][3]`?

Answer (score 3):

In Java indexes a zero based, which means that array: `new int[2][2];` will have two rows and two columns, and each of them will be indexed with 0..1.

In general if you declare and array, for instance of ints: `new int[n]` your index should go from 0 to n-1 (0,..,n-1). This is also the case with multidimensional arrays. Each dimension with size m will be indexed from 0 to m-1 (0,..,m-1) .

Answer (score 1):

`intsAssigned + 3;` doesn't modify the variable. You mean to do this:

```
intsAssigned += 3;
```

---

Also, this `static int[][] Placer = new int[2][2];` will create *length* 2 for the rows and columns, so the index positions for those will only be `0` and `1`

I think you want to change it to:

```
static int[][] Placer = new int[3][3];
```

---

Also this condition: `while(numbersPrinted != 9)` will always be true because you never incrememnt `numbersPrinted`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what dcsohl/user987339 have mentioned, there are a bunch of other mistakes in your code.

You never seem to increment numbersPrinted, so that while won't exit. Instead, currentColumn will keep going up until it's out of bounds. Just put in a

```
numbersPrinted += 3;
```

after you increment currentColumn in the second loop and that should be fixed.

Also, currentColumn is being initialized to 0 within the first loop, so it won't ever be anything but 0 whenever it's used. You should move

```
int currentColumn = 0;
```

to before the first while.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks, as you can probs tell I am a self-taught novice ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not initialized.

Here's an example of array

int[] x = {1, 3}

sum = x[0] + x[1].

Comment: A default value of 0 for arrays of integral types is guaranteed by the language spec:

Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10) [...] For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0. So the whole array will be initialized with zeroes.

If you want to initialize an array to a different value, you can use java.util.Arrays.fill() (which will of course use a loop internally).